# Difference between android:actionBarDivider and android:divider for ActionBar styles

Tags: android, android-styles

I noticed that documentation lists android:actionBarDivider and android:divider both as attributes to style the dividers between action items. I'm wondering what is difference and where would one use either or both (in the action bar style or in parent theme)?

Answer (score 1):

`android:divider` is the generic resource identifier for dividers between elements. It can be applied to a `LinearLayout`, `ListView`, etc.

`android:actionBarDivider` is just an identifier created to call out the `ActionBar` divider resource explicitly, [as seen in the Android source](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/styles_base.xml):

```
<style name="Widget.AppCompat.Base.ActionBar.TabBar" parent="">
    <item name="divider">?attr/actionBarDivider</item>
    <item name="showDividers">middle</item>
    <item name="dividerPadding">12dip</item>
</style>
```

In short, in the `ActionBar` themes, `android:divider` just points to `android:actionBarDivider`. You can specific either one, but both is not necessary.